# Self referencing loop detected for property 'project' with type 'Project'. Path 'project[0].requests[0]

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have this project mapping and I am struggling with JSON.NET serialization of the model.
I have tried with lazyloading = false, and disabled proxy as well. However, it is not working when I am Getting All projects with each projects requests.

Here is the mapping that I have:

```
Class ProjectMapper()
{
    this.HasMany(p => p.Stakeholders).WithMany(u => u.Projects).Map(mc =>
    {
        mc.MapLeftKey("ProjectID");
        mc.MapRightKey("UserID");
        mc.ToTable("userprojects");
    });

    this.HasMany(p => p.Requests).
        WithOptional(r => r.Project).HasForeignKey(r => r.ProjectID)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}

Class RequestMapper()
{
    this.HasOptional(r => r.Project).WithMany(p => p.Requests).HasForeignKey(r=>r.ProjectID);
}

Class UserMapper()
{
    this.HasMany(u => u.Projects).WithMany(p => p.Stakeholders).Map(mc =>
        {
            mc.MapLeftKey("ProjectID");
            mc.MapRightKey("UserID");
            mc.ToTable("userprojects");
        });
}
```

I have also changed the settings at global level:

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

But what is the solution ? Do I have to go to POCO model and copy all EF model to POCO before flushing out to the client.

Comment: Show your Project, Request and User class..

Comment: @YuliamChandra I am using Model directly to serialize with JSON.NET. Since I have just now disabled Lazyloading , and disabled proxy. It has started workin. However, there is a performance side effects as per the docuemnted performance suggestions from Microsoft, does that mean I should make another POCO (ViewModel) and automap (http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to these POCO?